# How to add a "select file" dialaog to a console application

Tags: c++, user-interface, console

Is there a way to add a select file dialog (as used in any gui prog) to a c++ console application? I do not want to transform my whole application into a forms application yet.

Comment: ¤ You can just call the relevant common dialog. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I'm not at all sure that Alf is correct!  Console apps are not designed to have a message queue / dispatch events / etc.  But you can make a Dialog project, which can often be a very simple way to make a basic Windows app without the work inherent in a forms app.

Comment: @ALF Yes from a "normal" forms or a vb application it is a piece of cake, but how do I call "the relevant common dialog" from a console app. It is not as esay as usual from there...

Answer (score 0):

Console applications usually run in a terminal. As such, they usually avoid file manipulations. They leave this task to the shell and use the redirections for file input and file output.

If you need an interactive user interface to choose a file name, then you have to call the GUI stuff of your system. But keep in mind that a console application may be run in a terminal environment without a graphical interface.

Edit:

As you're on Windows, you can use the standard windows calls to show up the file choose dialog. The C function for this is `GetOpenFileName`.

Otherwise, you can always ask the user to give the filename on the command line. You get it into your program through the `argc` and `argv` parameters of `main`.

Comment: The user has to tell the app where to find a ini file. For that that I would like the dialog, so that the user do not have to type the whole path. The app will always run on a windows system. I know how to use such i dialog in eg VB.net, but from a console I'm not sure which headers I need to get it working from within the console app.